# Inheriting NetworkInterface in C#

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, network-programming, network-interface

I have searched the web for examples of inheriting [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx) but I cannot see any elegant solutions to this. It appears that the static method `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` returns an internal implementation called `SystemNetworkInterface`.

Basically I want to inherit this into a class called `ManagedNetworkInterface` and add some additional functionality to it. Can anyone think of an elegant solution of how to do this? I have tried, but every time, something stops me dead in my tracks!

**EDIT 1:**

Is it acceptable to provide the implementation by casting the implementation back to `NetworkInterface` and then to `ManagedNetworkInterface`?

...this example seems messy!

```
ManagedNetworkInterface mni = (ManagedNetworkInterface)(NetworkInterface)NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()[0];
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have also thought of using a composition-like model...

```
public class ManagedNetworkInterface : NetworkInterface
{
    private NetworkInterface ni;

    public override string Description
    {
        get { return ni.Description; }
    }

    //ect...
}
```

Is this a good or bad idea?

Comment: Since the `NetworkInterface` returned is actually a `SystemNetworkInterface`, you'll get a runtime `InvalidCastException` if you try to cast it to your `ManagedNetworkInterface` type.

Comment: @tomfanning, Yes I discovered that already, hence the reason I am asking if it is a good idea to do a double cast, where SystemNetworkInterface is cast back to NetworkInterface, and then to ManagedNetworkInterface? it seems ugly to me!!

Comment: @activwerx: yes composition is a good idea: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: Casting via `NetworkInterface` or directly to `ManagedNetworkInterface` yields an equivalent operation. The object in question is a `SystemNetworkInterface` and can only ever be cast to its own type, `NetworkInterface`, or `System.Object`. Think about it - how would the framework know what to populate the extra properties of your `ManagedNetworkInterface` type with? So not just ugly - but it flat out won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. I have used composition to inherit and implement abstract class `NetworkInterface`

**Code**

```
public class ManagedNetworkInterface : NetworkInterface
{
    private NetworkInterface ni;

    public override string Description
    {
        get { return ni.Description; }
    }

    //ect...
}
```

The new class now includes several mechanisms for creating instances of ManagedNetworkInterface using things like IP Address, Physical Address, ID, Name etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would write an extension method for NetworkInterface

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void MyMethod(this NetworkInterface ni)
    {
          //Some Code
    }
}
```

and use as `ni.MyMethod()`

Comment: Sadly, the code must be portable (at least for now) to .NET 2.0 so I believe extension methods are OOTQ. But +1 for effort! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given that `NetworkInterface` doesn't have many properties, I chose to inherit `NetworkInterface`.

https://github.com/CodingOctocat/IPConfig/blob/master/IPConfig/Models/Nic.cs